# Show that Gram-Schmidt$(Y)$ = $B$Gram-Schmidt$(X)$ such that $B$ is an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices, gram-schmidt, stiefel-manifolds

Let $\begin{align}
V_{k,n} &= \Bigl \{ \begin{pmatrix}
           v_{1} \\
           v_{2} \\
           \vdots \\
           v_{k}
         \end{pmatrix} : v_i\in \mathbb{R}^n\text{ and } \{v_1,\cdots,v_k\}\text{ is linearly independent}\Bigr \}
  \end{align}
$. We say $X\sim Y$ if and only if $\exists A\in GL_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $Y = AX$ for $X,Y\in V_{k,n}$. Let us denote *Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization process* as **gs**.

Now, I need to show that **gs**$(Y) = B$**gs**$(X)$, such that $B$ is an orthogonal matrix. I understand that $B$ is an orthogonal matrix as **gs**$(Y)$ and **gs**$(X)$ are orthogonal matrices. It is that I cannot determine the matrix $B$ explicitly.

I would like somebody to help me computing the matrix $B$ explicitly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices and $U = BV$ then $B = UV^{-1} = UV^T$.